# (Android Studio, Kotlin) Image in Imageview is not displaying when clicked

Tags: android, kotlin

Hi all I have a problem in displaying image in ImageView when clicked, i made a function to display whenever the image was click I have already added the **android:onClick="drops"** in **.xml** in every imageview of my sample game, i used gridlayout(3x3) with 9 imageview

[image]

here is the code of the function.

```
    fun drops(view: View){

    val imageView = ImageView(this)

    var player = 0;
    if (player == 0){
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellow)
        imageView.animate().alpha(1f).rotation(360f).setDuration(600)
        player == 1
    }else {
        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.red)
        imageView.animate().alpha(1f).rotation(360f).setDuration(600)
        player == 0
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order for us to better help you, please describe the observed behavior of the function and how it differs from the expected behavior. Also please give your post a title that more specifically describe the problem so others with the same issue can find it in search results.

Comment: Are you getting any error? I think you have to use `view` instead of `imageView`

Comment: Hi @grrigore there is no error an already tried your suggestion but nothing is displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure in what class is this function contained, I suppose it is either in a `Fragment` or `Activity`. As you said, you're binding the image views with `drops` method in the xml layout.

What could be the problem is this line:

```
val imageView = ImageView(this)
```

From your question we cannot see which class is this method defined in, so expression `this` could be anything. You might me instantiating an `ImageView` from the whole Activity or Fragment object, and cannot work in way you would like to. So I suggest to rewrite this line to something like this:

```
val imageView = view as ImageView
```

The function `drops` receives a single `View` parameter, which is the image view the user clicked - but `View` class has no method called `setImageResource`, so you need to cast it to the desired subtype (ImageView is subclass of View). This should do the job.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation it solves my problem.